# How to auto dismiss NSAlert on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to create NSAlert (popup) show and then auto close. It same click on Button, it show popup Scanning... , after found any items, popup Scanning auto dismiss. And when popup show, user cannot click any button on my app. How can i do that? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below code will help you

```
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender {
    //display the alert
    self.myAlert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Sample Test" defaultButton:@"OK" alternateButton:@"DO Nothing" otherButton:@"CANCEL" informativeTextWithFormat:@"TEST",nil];
    [self.myAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window]
                         modalDelegate:self
                        didEndSelector:@selector(errorAlertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                           contextInfo:nil];

    NSArray *buttonArray = [self.myAlert buttons];
    NSLog(@"Button Arrays %@",buttonArray);

    //Close by itself without a mouse click by the user
    //Assuming the Default Button as the Second one "Do Nothing
    NSButton *myBtn = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:2];
    [myBtn performClick:self.myAlert];
```

}

Comment: Thanks but i don't want add any button on alert. And can you show me how to dismiss nsalert when call another function ?

Comment: This worked for me: [self.myAlert.window orderOut:self]; [self.myAlert.window close];

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSAlert(AutoDismiss)
- (void) dismiss;
- (void) dismissAfter: (CGFloat) seconds completion: (void (^)(void)) completion;
@end

@implementation NSAlert(AutoDismiss)

- (void) dismiss {
    NSButton* closeButton = self.buttons.lastObject;
    if (closeButton) {
        [closeButton performClick: self];
    }
}

- (void) dismissAfter: (CGFloat) seconds completion: (void (^)(void)) completion {
    __block NSAlert* weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf dismiss];
        if (completion) {
            completion();
        }
    });
}

@end
```